# PowerShell: I'm trying to generate a shortcut on my desktop via a PS Script and the following error occures

Tags: powershell

This is the code I user for generating the shortcut:

```
    $TargetFile = "$disk\dbadl\db_dl.ps1"
$ShortcutFile = "C:\Dropbox Autodownload.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "$disk\dbadl\ico\dbabl.ico"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

and this is the error I get when running the script:

```
The shortcut "C:\Dropbox Autodownload.lnk" wasn't saved.
In C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\install.ps1:34 Char:1
+ $Shortcut.Save()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have access to write to the root of `C:` - are you running this script elevated (ie. "Run As Administrator...")?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Yes I do and with some other code in the script I can write to C:

Comment: Is your intention ro have PowerShell run the script? (the default action on a ps1 file is to open it in Notepad)